# PIXI.js custom filter error: calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix is not a function

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am building a simple custom shader and using this code to normalize the screen space but it always throws the following error:

`filterManager.calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix is not a function`

```
        let myFilter = new PIXI.Filter(null, fragShader, uniforms);
    myFilter.apply = function( filterManager, input, output, clear ){
        let matrix = new PIXI.Matrix();
        this.uniforms.filterMatrix = filterManager.calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix
        (matrix);
        filterManager.applyFilter(this, input, output, clear);
    }
```

This is Pixi.js definition for `calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix`:

```
    /**
 * Multiply vTextureCoord to this matrix to achieve (0,0,1,1) for filterArea
 *
 * @param {PIXI.Matrix} outputMatrix - The matrix to output to.
 * @return {PIXI.Matrix} The mapped matrix.
 */
calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix(outputMatrix)
{
    const currentState = this.filterData.stack[this.filterData.index];
    return filterTransforms.calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix(
        outputMatrix,
        currentState.sourceFrame,
        currentState.renderTarget.size,
        currentState.destinationFrame
    );
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What worked was to use `calculateSpriteMatrix` function instead.
Apparently, `calculateNormalizedScreenSpaceMatrix` will not work for Pixi.js V7